# Typescript required type based on value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and I was wondering if there is a way to make a type required based on the value of another type:

```
type TextInput = {
    isValid?: boolean;
    validMessage?: string;
}
```

Is it possible to make `validMessage` required if `isValid` becomes true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use discriminated unions:

```js
type Valid = {
    isValid: true;
    validMessage: string
}

type Invalid = {
    isValid: false;
}

type TextInput = Valid | Invalid


const foo = (props: TextInput) => {
    if (props.isValid) {
        props.validMessage // ok
    } else {
        props.isValid // false
        props.validMessage // error
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDUCGAbAlgE1gXlgb2LIbKgM5JroBcsoATgK7QDcBRAbihgLLQkmIBzaNRJ1UAOwHAAviAgxYASXEcK2PK0KlyGagDMUJZjLlQ4AFWgAPUMsj1Q6nZgA%20SlZ3QhgAYwD24qKwen5%206gAUkLR%20kCTUljZ2DgCU2AB8GkTEerCR0bEAdNqeqfhZWVExJAWq3Lz8QrAA9E2wfgDWmrDSsNDIRpnlhJWFxWotwYbQXRX51bXoPHyCcBPQtNG0XbLSQA)

See also related [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)